# What programming language / obfuscation is this?

Tags: xml, encryption, obfuscation, reverse-engineering

I have a program which stores its keyboard bindings as a large obfuscated or encrypted file. I am trying to find out what type of encryption it is, but am unsure as to where else to explore from here. It's contained in an XML file without any comment or hint (the field name is DeviceIO.Config.Controller)

```
The whole line is: 
Entry Name="DeviceIO.Config.Controller" Type="3"         Value="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         (edited for brevity...)
```

Scroll to the right to see the sample. Where can I start? Or failing that, what resources exist for me to have an understanding of how to approach a problem like this?

Comment: Well, that looks a lot like base64 encoded data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the end of the text-blob. Does it end with an = (equals sign)? If so, chances are it's a [Base64-encoded string,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which isn't an encryption as much as it's a way to store binary data in a text-compatible fashion, although I've seen places where it was used as a (very) basic form of obfuscation when what you're storing isn't meant to be *secure*, as much as just not directly in the spotlight.

Since this seems to be an XML attribute value, it's possible that the data contains characters that aren't XML-friendly (such as ", <, & or others) and the developers decided it was easier to just Base64-encode it all, rather than escaping the invalid XML characters specifically.

It's very easy to reverse, and most programming frameworks have built-in utilties for it. .NET, for instance, has the [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) method. I'm guessing it's as easy in other languages.

Comment: Looks like you are right! The end of the field is `lAGUAbg==`. I ran this through an online base64 decoder tool, and it gave a large number of fields, with values like this: 
`Left.Play?€DCDT,
Right.Play?€DCDT6`
Any guesses for those? I am very fuzzy on the specifics of how a value can be mistaken for an unicode character markup...

Comment: Sorry, those don't look familiar. It's possible it's a custom format used by the app to store their keyboard bindings, rather than a standard. The `?€` looks like a delimiter, but I do't know what DCDT might represent.

Comment: I assume that the values are incrimented from each other (they are controls that are close together), and may identify some sort... is proper stack overflow behavior to create a new topic for this followup question, or to use comments / pms? thanks!

Comment: I think this question - on how the textblob is obfuscated - is over and done with. Followups should have their own questions.